# GPG key skipped during maven release

Tags: maven-gpg-plugin

I am following all the instructions listed here to release my project to sonatype repo: https://dzone.com/articles/publish-your-artifacts-to-maven-central
But still getting the following error during signing artifacts

```
[INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) @ exceptionless-client ---
gpg: skipped "0x9d0e3e1d": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  42.750 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-03T10:52:18+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-gpg-plugin:3.0.1:sign (sign-artifacts) on project exceptionless-client: Exit code: 2 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rezad the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I can see the key listed when I run `gpg --list-key` command.

Answer (score 1):

I used git bash to generate new keys, but I didn't know that git bash also comes with a bundled `gpg` program and it was using that. However, the `maven-gpg-plugin` was trying to find keys using the gpg program installed under `C:/Program Files(x86)`. After I created keys using this I installed it worked perfectly.